# Which algorithm should I use for clustering words based on sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following problem.

I have a big dataset which contains rows of words.
so i.e.

```
apple,door,wood
window,door,house
boot,pie,dessert
```

I want to create 4 categories out of all these words and then match a new line of words to one of the 4 categories. The words in a single row are somehow connected but I don't have any info about how I just get the lines of words.

Is there an algorithm in scikit-learn or other python package which I can use for this?

EDIT:

I see I have given to little information.

The words can be keywords of a webpage in example and then I want to select a category based on those keywords so I can make a suggestion on what to read as a next article.

However I don't want to create to many categories so I want to combine categories. So i.e. if it turns out 'dog' is a lot of times in the same row as 'house' then I can suggest 'house' if 'dog' is present in de keywords.

I don't want to set the categories up front, I want to get the groups first and then create a category which matches the words best.

Comment: As it stands, your question is very unclear and broad. What are the categories? Do you want to classify lines or individual words? What have you tried so far? scikit-learn provides implementations for many different machine-learning algorithms.

Comment: Are the words you have in your dataset all different ? Or do you find any "pattern" like for example words that often repeat themselves ? Can you count the number of different words you have ?

Comment: @EliKorvigo I added more information. I'm just starting with scikit so don't know much algo's yet. But I thought about kmeans or minibatch but wouldn't know how to do this with multiple sets.

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to generate word representations instead? If so you could create word vectors by using [gensims word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). What you could do is use each line as the sentence and remove the commas, then you would learn what words go together, and words with similar contexts will have similar word embeddings. You could then run k-means over the word vectors themselves and get a better cluster based on representations.

From your question, if you know that specific words always come together and want to create categories thats one step, but at that point I don't think you would need to use k-means, unless ofcourse thats not the case and you could have any combinations of words, and would like to figure out which combinations are similar, in that case you could set each word to an integer id so `apple` is `1`, `door` -> `2`, `wood` -> `3` and so on and so forth. Then a vector like the first example would look like `[1,1,1,0,....0]`. The problem here is that K-means will do poorly with such vectors though and you're better of building word embeddings if you just don't know the pattern of words that go together.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.